# TypeScript and Angular Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

When writing services in `TypeScript` for `AngularJS` do you define a model for the request and the response?

So for example, given the following service call into a RESTFul endpoint from the service:

```
module Application {
    export module Services {
        export class MyService {
            public static $inject = ["$http"];

            constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            }

            getSomeData = (model: Models.RequestModel): ng.IPromise<Models.ResponseModel> => {
                this.$http.post("url", model).then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Models.ResponseModel>) => {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I am sending the `RequestModel` and receiving back the `ResponseModel`

Would that be the proper use/syntax?

Answer (score 2):

> So basically I am sending the RequestModel and receiving back the ResponseModel, Would that be the proper use/syntax?

Yes. Request in, promise to Response out.

Comment: So do I need to use the `Models` I am using or is that overkill? Does this look like a good solution/pattern? Thanks!!

Comment: IMHO using the `module` keyword is generally an overkill : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md You can put interfaces in a global namespace in a non external module and use external modules everywhere else

Comment: Could you provide an example of the above in the way that you feel is the right way to write it? You dont have ti use modules?